# Error on Importing Stripe Library into Eclipse

Tags: android

Following the tutorial: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android

I simply download the **stripe-android library**.

Every time I go to import it into Eclipse I get an error asking me to **remove the main**. I removed main but still get the error.

This is the error:

[image]

Comment: I think you are doing wrong import. You should import project as Android project...

Comment: Read more at http://techforpassion.blogspot.in/2013/03/Eclipse-create-project-from-existing-source.html

Comment: I am Going Import -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace. And then I select the folder I downloaded from their website?

Comment: Yes right? See the added link

Comment: Yes I have imported correctly as a copy, still all red xs beside my src files. :/

Comment: Still getting: The import com.stripe.android cannot be resolved

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I didn't have  **Android SDK with API Level 17**. I intalled it and then tried the import again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Installation

1-First download the stripe-android libraries.
2-Be sure you've installed the Android SDK with API Level 17 and android-support-v4
3- Import the stripe folder into Eclipse.
4- In your project settings, add the stripe project under the "Libraries" section of the "Android" category.